# I have a doubt for a combinatorics question below and want to know where am I going wrong.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

In how many different ways can 3 men and 4 women be placed into two groups of two people and one group of three people if there must be at least one man and one woman in each group? Note that identically sized groups are indistinguishable.

grp$1(1M$ and $1W)$---------------grp$2(1M$ and $1W)$-----------------grp$3(1M$ and $2W$).

so for grp 1 we have 3 choices of men and 4 choices of women(3×4). for grp2 we are left with 2 men and 3 women so we have 2 choices for men and 3 choices for women(2×3). And for grp 3 we are left with 1 men and 2 women which is 1 whole grp choice(1).

so equation becomes $3×4×2×3×1=72$. But the answer is half of it $36$. I would appreciate your answer to make me understand where am I wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Identically sized groups are indistinguishable" -- did you use this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be very clear in the concept for problems of forming teams/groups from people (ie distinct objects)

Basically it depends on whether groups are  distinct (better terminology is **labeled**) (eg group A, group  B, etc) or unlabeled.

A further very important point to note is that even if groups have not been given names, they automatically become labeled by size (eg three groups of $4,3,1$) or composition (eg men,women).

Now if groups are **unlabeled** eg two groups of two people,
$AB\mid CD \equiv CD\mid AB$, and because we can't distinguish between them, we need to divide by $2!$

Here we have groups $(2W,1M),\;\; (1W,1M),\;\; (1W,1M)$
Since the last two groups are **unlabeled**, we need to divide by $2!$
*[Don't forget the factorial, had all three groups been unlabeled, we would need to divide by $3!$, not $3$ ]*

Answer (score 0):

Start with men. Make all $3$ of them stand separately

Now each man represents one **distinct** group

First we have to divide **$4$** distinct women as **$1+1+2$**. This can be done in **$\dfrac{4!}{(1!)^2(2!)(2!)} = 6$** ways

Now we have to distribute them in $3$ distinct groups (of men). This can be done in **$6 × 3! = 36$** ways

Hence the answer is $36$

**PS**: If you find any difficulty in understanding this answer, do read the topic *Division and Distribution of Distinct Objects* under *Permutations & Combinations*